# How to play sound on specific frame of animation?

Tags: aframe

I have an animated model that lasts  220 frames. On frame 70, I want to send an event in order to play some audio. How can I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to edit the audio to have 70 frames of silence at the start, then play the audio with the animation.

Comment: Thanks, was hoping for a more integrated way to do it. Regards.